# Survey123 Table to Heat Map Online

Tags: arcgis-survey123

One of the things my team is trying to accomplish this semester is creating a Survey123 for Lake Management field work with an online interactive map to show field results.

For example, during the winter season, a probe is dropped into the lake through the ice and measures the dissolved oxygen and temperature every 1m on its way down to the bottom. This creates a profile of the lake.

We want to create a table in Survey123 like the one below and spit out a result like this:

[image]

[image]

I was wondering if you have experience or know how to upload the Survey123 table automatically to an online map.

How do we show something like this on a map?

I’ve been searching online for quite sometime and was wondering if you could point me in the right direction.